# Configure PhpStorm Run gutter icons

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm, webstorm, phpstorm-2017.1

Since updating to 2017.1 I've noticed these Run gutter icons in my Karma files.

They look cool and could be useful, however when I click them they run as pure node instead of using the Karma plugin.

Is there a way of configuring these icons to use Karma as the default configuration instead of Node?

[image: Gutter run icons]

Comment: Could be related to the fact that IDE currently does not support running individual Karma test -- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-13173

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this can't be configuraed.

Running individual karma tests is not yet supported, please follow [WEB-13173](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-13173) for updates.

WebStorm tries to run your tests with other available runners instead, this usability issue is tracked as [WEB-25932](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-25932)

Comment: Thanks, shame, but I'm patient enough.  I'll just have to keep remembering to remove the `f` in `fdescribe`, tch! :P